# UART takes some "kicking" to start receiving data

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, uart

I am using a UART on a single board computer (Olimex A13) and I am trying to send and receive data through the UART. On the send side I have no problems. The Olimex board sends data to the serial buss and it is received on an external PC that is running putty terminal.

When I try to go in the other direction (PC sends data to be received by the Olimex board) I am running into a weird problem. When I start to send data, initially no data shows up on the Olimex board (I have tried 2 methods... cat /dev/ttyS0 and setting up a receive C program. Both exhibit the same results).

If I send data for a while (seems to vary from less than 10 characters to something over 20) at some point the uart seems to "wake up" and now data appears on the Olimex board. Once the data transfer starts it will keep going as long as I want and at fast or slow data rates. If I break out of the receive program or end the cat /dev/ttyS0 process and try to start receiving again, I need to go through the same process of "kicking" the uart until it decides it wants to receive again.

I have put an oscilloscope on the RX pin leading into the UART. The data coming in is at good levels and the data appears here from the very first send so the data is not being blocked initially and then arriving at the RX pin at some time later. So I am currently assuming that the issue is with a UART setting of some kind. Does anyone know of a UART setting that could possibly explain this behavior?

Below is the receive program that I am running. I don't think that there is an issue with it because I see the same behavior when I do a cat /dev/ttyS0. Any help here would be appreciated.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BAUDRATE B115200
#define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyS0"
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 /* POSIX compliant source */
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

  volatile int STOP=FALSE;

  main()
  {
    int fd,c, res;
    struct termios oldtio,newtio;
    char buf[255];

    fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
    if (fd <0) {perror(MODEMDEVICE); return(-1); }

    tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio); /* save current port settings */

    bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));
    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;

    /* set input mode (non-canonical, no echo,...) */
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;

    newtio.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;   /* inter-character timer unused */
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 1;   /* blocking read until 5 chars received */

    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);


    while (STOP==FALSE) {       /* loop for input */
      res = read(fd,buf,255);   /* returns after 5 chars have been input */
      buf[res]=0;               /* so we can printf... */
      printf("String:%s - Character Count:%d\n", buf, res);
      if (buf[0]=='z') STOP=TRUE;
    }
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
  }
```

Sawdust made these comments....

> "sends data to the serial buss" -- RS232 is not a "buss". "When I
>   start to send data" -- Your writing style is confusing. What kind of
>   data is sent to the Olimex? For the cat /dev/ttyS0 test, how did you
>   set up the serial port, or was it in an unknown mode? bzero(&newtio,
>   sizeof(newtio)); -- That is a dangerous way to setup the termios
>   structure.  newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE... That is not the proper way to
>   set the baud rate; you need to use the cfset[io]speed() functions. You
>   write of a "kick", yet you don't mention doing anything explicit

ok, RS232 is not a buss, I misspoke....

The data I am sending is a stream of characters that are typed on Putty terminal.

For the /dev/ttyS0 test the settings are the same as are set in the c program. I verified this using stty.

I copied this code from another post. I was not sure what bzero did. If you could expand on "dangerous" that would be great. Or better if you have a better way to do what bzero does?

I will update the way to set baud rate.. but send is working perfectly and I verified using stty that baudrate was indeed 115200.

As far as "kicking" I mean that I need to send a number of bytes of data to the uart before any appear on the console. Others have mentioned a FIFO that may be an issue here but the first characters that are sent are lost. For example if I were to send the string of characters abcdefg.... I could type up until k and then l would appear on the console, and then any future characters after l would also appear in the console. If I were to go through the same process again after starting the receive program (or cat /dev/ttyS0) the point where the receive starts appearing could be in a different place (i.e. at h or n).

Comment: Disable the UART's internal FIFO buffer?  But then you might run the risk of losing data if the baud rate is high...

Comment: *"sends data to the serial buss"* -- RS232 is not a "buss". *"When I start to send data"* -- Your writing style is confusing. What kind of data is sent to the Olimex? For the `cat /dev/ttyS0` test, how did you set up the serial port, or was it in an unknown mode? `bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));` -- That is a dangerous way to setup the termios structure.  `newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE...`  That is not the proper way to set the baud rate; you need to use the `cfset[io]speed()` functions. You write of a "kick", yet you don't mention doing anything explicit

Comment: *"Or better if you have a better way to do what bzero does?"* -- [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)